# HighQualityBicubic interpolation adds black background during resizing

Tags: c#, image-processing, background, transparency, gdi+

I'm implementing image scaling function. When I use HighQualityBicubic interpolation mode (which is preferred from quality perspective) I'm getting black background on resized image(only in rectangle of source image. In padding area of destination rectangle it is still transparent).
Input image is bmp with transparent background.
Output is also bmp 32 bpp.
Interesting thing when I change InterpolationMode to NearestNeighbor with some input images background is preserved as transparent after resizing and with another inputs it doesn't help.
What I'm doing wrong?

```
public Bitmap DrawScaledImage(Image img, int width, int height, int scaledWidth, int scaledHeight)
    {
        var resultImg = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        resultImg.SetResolution(img.HorizontalResolution, img.VerticalResolution);
        using (Graphics grPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(resultImg))
        {
            grPhoto.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            grPhoto.DrawImage(img,
                new Rectangle(0, 0, scaledWidth, scaledHeight), //0;0 - image is drawn in left top corner
                new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height),
                GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
        return resultImg;
    }
```

[image: Input image]
[image: Output image]

**Update**
Found funny thing:
I've picked random transparent pixel in source image and took its ARGB in debug: it is ARGB=(255, 0, 0, 0) - pretty clear
Then I've picked same pixel which was intended to be transparent in destination image after scaling and it is still ARGB=(255, 0, 0, 0) but in Paint.Net it is displayed as black.
Then I've picked another random pixel from destination image that is displayed as transparent in Paint.Net and its ARGB schema is ARGB=(0, 0, 0, 0) - what?

So maybe stupid question - why for 1st pic transparent pixel is [255;0;0;0] but for 2nd [255;0;0;0] means black and transparent is [0;0;0;0].
it looks like something went down-under. and Alfa-channel reversed its meaning from 255- transparent to 255-opaque after scaling. Any ideas?
[image: Source pic]
[image: Destination pic]
[image: Debug]

Comment: You may want to set the background of the new bitmap to transparent before drawing the resized version: `grPhoto.Clear(Color.Transparent)`.

Comment: @TaW thanks for hint. Unfortunately It doesn't change anything in result image. I tried this already and just rechecked again. Also tried `resultImg.MakeTransparent();`

Comment: It is not so much a hint as a requirement. Can you post an original image and the (wrong) result or are the images you posted just that? (No, the 1st image has a white center) - Also note that many apps can't properly display transparency, IrfanView for example will display it as black..(But .Net Paint should work fine)

Comment: @TaW here source and result are: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1m8ztoVTIsUYQXPbRp7vjMPa77chxMcAM?usp=sharing
you can try to resize source using my above code - I guess you will get same result with black background
And as I mentioned - if you set `grPhoto.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;` It will resize with transparent background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found that reason is some buggy behavior saving file in BMP format after resizing with `InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic`. Here are cases for reproduction:
1. If I create brand new image with pixel format `PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb` make some program manipulations with pixels (e.g. paint some line) and save as bmp - no problem at all, transparency is saved and visible in Paint.Net.
2. If I open existing bmp image already with transparency scale it up/down with `Graphics.DrawImage` method all seems good in debug. Transparent pixels have Alpha = 0. Then I save that image as bmp. Then Open it again in code like `Image.FromFile("resized.bmp")` and its pixel format is not same as it was before saving: it is now `Format32bppRgb` however saved image had `Format32bppArgb`. On opened image transparent pixels now have Alpha = 255. This is the cause why opening in Paint.Net I see black instead of transparent after resizing.

I found 2 workarounds to preserve transparency after resizing:
1. Change `InterpolationMode` from `InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic` to  `InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor`. This solves transparency issue but not acceptable due to low quality method.
2. Save resized image as .png. This saves correct Alpha values and reopening image preserves it still. So it is my solution to refuse using BMP file format at all.

Comment: I was guessing something like that (but had no time to research so far) - Even Photoshop CS2 doesn't understand the 'new' 32bit BMP format, so why would GDI+ ?-) - (Still one has to wonder what the InterpolationMode has to do with it???)

Comment: @TaW right. I'm not so strong in this topic so will leave interpolation to someone else:) thanks for support anyway.